# Как запустить tor через последний узел?

Tags: python, парсер, tor

я пишу скрипт на питоне, который через тор обращается к какому-то сайту. Как сделать так, чтобы весь трафик шел через последний узел?
В torrc я раскомментировал следующие строки:

```
SOCKSPort 9050 # Default: Bind to localhost:9050 for local connections.
ControlPort 9051
HashedControlPassword <пароль>
ExitNodes {US},{DE},{AT},{UA},{RU}
StrictExitNodes 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, в тор-протоколе Вы не можете указать, через какую ноду "работать". Фактически, нельзя даже узнать, какая нода была использована.

Единственное, что Вы можете сказать - из каких "локаций" использовать ноды. Потому что переключение с ноды на ноду - это особенность протокола, которая как раз и делает его "более безопасным".

Эта оговорка - "более безопасным" не зря взята в кавычки: дело в том, что если видеть запись всех пересылок пакетов между узлами, и знать время, когда произошло обращение к какому то серверу, то можно "раскрутить назад" последовательность соединений. А именно запись всех заголовков пакетов является частью той мета - информации, котрую собирают системы сорм и им подобные.

И, к сожалению, очень многие публичные сервисы (такие, как почтовые серверы и т.п.) относятся к соединениям с узлов tor очень подозрительно, иногда просто отказываясь работать с таким соединением.